# How would you say a person has made a choice out of being of noble character?

Tags: phrasing, paraphrasing, adjective-position

Let us say a person is noble/of noble character/noble-hearted. As in, he isn't a person of a social rank of nobility, but rather is a good, selfless person.

I'd like to say that this person has done a great thing out of his noble character. Would I be able to say "He decided to stay out of **nobility**"? - or would that imply noble in the meaning of social rank?

If not, how would I say it?

Comment: "He decided to stay out of nobility" is ambiguous, as "out of" can mean outside/avoiding, or can give a reason. So it might mean he avoided nobility, or he stayed because of nobility.

Answer (score 1):

He decided to stay where he was out of chivalry.

Being naturally noble, he decided to stay.

He decided to stay in the spirit of noblesse oblige.